# why the linear gradient not applied in the bottom of this form but when zoomed out it's no more

Tags: html, css

It is the project of freecodecamp survey form project. I don't know why this happens trying to debug it but no use.

[Normal zoom (100%)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPaYa.png)

[zoomed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgxef.png)

Here is the Html and CSS

```css
body {
  font-family: "Ubuntu";
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 100, 200, 40), rgba(0, 200, 50, 40));
}

h1,
p {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

form {
  min-width: 400px;
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 70vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

fieldset {
  padding: 1em 0;
  border: none;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

input,
select,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 2.5em;
  margin: 1em 0 0 0;
}

select,
textarea {
  height: 3.5em;
}

.inline {
  width: unset;
  margin: 0 0.5em 0 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}


input[type="submit"] {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

#bottom {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Application Form</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 id="title">Application Form</h1>
    <p id="description">Fill the following details.</p>
    <form id="survey-form" action="#">
        <fieldset>

            <label id="name-label" for="name">Name
                <input id="name" required type="text" placeholder="Ex: John Legend">
            </label>

            <label id="email-label" for="email">Email
                <input id="email" required type="email" placeholder="Ex: john@legend.com">
            </label>

            <label id="number-label" for="number">Age
                <input id="number" required type="number" min="18" max="60" placeholder="Ex: 35">
            </label>

            <label for="tech-dropdown">Technology
                <select id="tech-dropdown" name="technology">
                    <option value="tech1">Go</option>
                    <option value="tech2">Java</option>
                    <option value="tech3">Python</option>
                    <option value="tech4">C++</option>
                </select>
            </label>

            <label for="exp-dropdown">Years of Experience
                <select id="exp-dropdown" name="experience">
                    <option value="1">No Experience</option>
                    <option value="2">
                        &lt 2 years</option>
                    <option value="3">
                        &lt 5 years</option>
                    <option value="4">
                        &lt 10 years</option>
                </select>
            </label>

        </fieldset>

        <fieldset id="bottom">

            <legend>Gender</legend>
            <label for="male"><input class="inline" checked id="male" name="option" value="male" type="radio">
                Male</label>
            <label for="female"><input class="inline" id="female" name="option" value="female" type="radio">
                Female</label>
            <label for="others"><input class="inline" id="others" name="option" value="others" type="radio">
                Others</label>
            <label for="bio">Tell us about yourself<textarea id="bio" name="bio" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></label>
        </fieldset>
        <label for="agreement"><input class="inline" id="agreement" value="agreement" required type="checkbox">I accept
            the terms and conditions</label>
        <label for="subscribe"><input class="inline" id="subscribe" value="subscribe" required type="checkbox">Subscribe
            to our newsletter</label>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Due to nature of this error/my lack of searching skill I can't find any answers online. Even tried chatgpt but still haven't found any solution or even know the the cause.

Comment: `height: 100vh;` is probably the issue. Try `min-height: 100vh;` instead.